# Dataweave to remove json elements from values after groupBy | Mule 3.9

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to transform an xml based on groupBy in dataweave, however I also need to remove few json attributes from output.

Input json:

```
[   {
    "m": {
      "a": "a",
      "b": "b"
    },
    "tag1": "A",
    "tag2": "v1",
    "tag3": "v1"   },   {
    "m": {
      "a": "a",
      "b": "b"
    },
    "tag1": "A",
    "tag2": "v2",
    "tag3": "v2"   },   {
    "m": {
      "a": "a",
      "b": "b"
    },
    "tag1": "C",
    "tag2": "v3",
    "tag3": "v3"   } ]
```

Output json

```
 **{
  "A": [
    {
      "tag2": "v1",
      "tag3": "v1"
    },
    {
      "tag2": "v2",
      "tag3": "v2"
    }
  ],
  "C": {
    "tag2": "v3",
    "tag3": "v3"
  }
}**
```

I have tried following transformation  (Mule 3.9) however the could not remove the extra attributes in json.

```
payload groupBy (item) -> item.tag1
```

Appreciate any suggestion on this and possibly explain how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

The way to iterate over an object is using mapObject and then you can filter the objects to remove the elements that are not wanted

```
{a: [1,2,3], b: [2,3]} mapObject ((value,key) -> 
    {
       (key): value filter ((value, index) -> value > 2)
    }
 )
```

This will output

```
{
  "a": [
    3
  ],
  "b": [
    3
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! however, I need to remove values from array which has created after groupBy operation. basically this is an hashmap and I am not sure how to iterate hashmap and remove the elements from values against keys.

Comment: Ok then I have updated you can use mapObject and filter

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate your help.